# inline static variable in different translation units has different values(c++17)

Tags: c++, static, c++17, inline

I want to implement a source file that contains a global variable, and I want to do this through `inline static`. I can change a variable (e.g., `i`) within the context of a translation unit, but when I call the variable outside of that translation unit, the result will remain unchanged for the caller. It's like there is a copy for each unit. See the below example:

### header.h

```
#ifndef UNTITLED1_TEST_H
#define UNTITLED1_TEST_H

namespace t {
    inline static int i{0};

    void inc() ;

    void print_i() ;
}

#endif //UNTITLED1_TEST_H
```

### header.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

void t::inc() {
    t::i++;
}

void t::print_i() {
    std::cout << t::i << std::endl;
}
```

So let's see how the program performs:

### main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main() {
    t::inc();

    std::cout << t::i << std::endl; // -> output is: 0
    t::print_i(); // -> output is : 1
}
```

As you can see, the variable `i` has different values across different translation units, how can this be resolved? I cannot use classes or anything else since the client wants the code in this format.

### note

I can do such things as below, but it isn't the main issue, I want a global variable:

```
t::i++; //instead of t::inc();
std::cout << t::i << std::endl; // it's okay now, but it's not what I wanted
```

Alternatively, I can use `inline` instead of `inline static`. It seems to be working, but my mentor said that I should use `inline static` instead.

Comment: Global static variable accessed outside the file scope, does it really compile?

Comment: @kiner_shah, yes, it's compiled in c++17.

Comment: `static` variables have **internal linkage**. Different translation units will have different variables.

Comment: Static (in a namespace) and global are two opposite things. Either do not declare it static or declare it static *in a class*.

Comment: `static` *prevents* it from being global, and `inline`, if it means anything at all here, means 'per translation unit'. So *both* keywords you're using are 100% wrong for your purpose.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Thanks, But I'm really confused how can I implement such a thing, is it wrong to use `inline` for this purpose?

Comment: No it should stay inline. Just not namespace-static. It can be class-static (the keyword static means two very different things in these two cases).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, I am confused by his statement. However, I wonder if using inline in this instance will prevent it from being copied in different translation units? By testing it, I have confirmed it, but I need to know (if you can help me with some development)! Sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` variables (as in your example) have **internal linkage**. There are 2 ways to achieve what you want, both of which are shown below. Also note that the `static` keyword has other meanings as well.

##### Method 1: C++17

With C++17, we can use the `inline` keyword as shown below:

**header.h**

```cpp
#ifndef UNTITLED1_TEST_H
#define UNTITLED1_TEST_H

namespace t {
    inline int i{0};//note the keyword inline here and initializer while keyword static has been removed 

    void inc() ;

    void print_i() ;
}

#endif
```

**header.cpp**

```cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

//No need for initilaizing t::i here

void t::inc() {
    t::i++;
}

void t::print_i() {
    std::cout << t::i << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include"header.h"

int main() {
    t::inc();

    std::cout << t::i << std::endl; // -> output is: 1
    t::print_i(); // -> output is : 1
}
```

The output of method 1 can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/u5hXS2ED2o).

##### Method 2: Pre-C++17

Here we make use of the `extern` keyword so that the variable can have **external linkage**.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include"header.h"

int main() {
    t::inc();

    std::cout << t::i << std::endl; // -> output is: 1
    t::print_i(); // -> output is : 1
}
```

**header.h**

```cpp
#ifndef UNTITLED1_TEST_H
#define UNTITLED1_TEST_H

namespace t {
    extern int i;//note the keyword extern and no initializer here

    void inc() ;

    void print_i() ;
}

#endif
```

Note I have removed added the `static` and `inline` keywords, and added the `extern` keyword. Now the variable has **external linkage**. Also, note that the initialization of `t::i` is done in **header.cpp** given below.

**header.cpp**

```cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

int t::i{}; //initialize t::i

void t::inc() {
    t::i++;
}

void t::print_i() {
    std::cout << t::i << std::endl;
}
```

Output of the above program is: [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/6vpY2YBPQ)

```
1
1
```

Also, do note that the keyword `static` has other meanings as well. But I have answered according to the given example code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my mentor said that in c++17 the `inline static` has replaced the `extern`, so you should use that, is he wrong about that?

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi You've proven it.

Comment: @user207421, yeah kind of :)

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi Yes he(your mentor) is wrong in saying that.

Comment: The `static` is only needed when the variable is a class member. For this case, your mentor is right. At namespace level, `static` has a different meaning and must not occur to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

There are many different meanings of the keyword `static`, depending on context. You are using `static` in a wrong context. You can do this

```
namespace t {
     inline int i{0}; // no static
}
```

or this

```
class t {
  public:
     inline static int i{0};
}:
```

All of this should be in a header file, with no other definition in a .cpp file and no `extern` keyword. These things are required in C++14 or earlier, but not in C++-17 or later.